# Object file doesn't contain DWARF debug information

Tags: ios, xcode4

I am getting the following error in Xcode 4 when attempting to build:

> libIOSCoreSDK.a(Logging.o) object file doesn't contain DWARF debug
>   information

My Xcode workspace contains two projects a SDK project which compiles the static library `libIOSCoreSDK.a` and a UI project which is linked to use the static library.

I have a number of classes in the SDK which I use in the UI and none of them have resulted in the above error until now.

Comment: Have you tried going to the libIOSCoreSDK project, selecting the target, clicking on the build settings tab and ensuring that "Debug Information Format" is set to DWARF?

Comment: Yep, I've double and triple checked that.

Answer (score 3):

Its a static library, you need to rebuild it with debug turned on.